# Removing Quotation Marks in WordPress music player

Tags: php, wordpress, audio-player

I would like to remove the "quotation" mark in the WordPress music player.
I have been told its in the media.php file, but it is too complicated for me knowledge.
anyone have an idea?
[Link to Web Page](https://eyal-rich.com/music/)

thanks in advance
dor.

Comment: No code, no help. If it's a server-side setting, there's no way we can tell.

Comment: Hi, dor can you tell how, you have added this playlist into your page?

Comment: with a shortcode.

Comment: how can I upload the file here?